# moment.js: convert timestamp and show month in German

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have troubles displaying the month of the following operation in German:

```
var date = moment.unix(valueTimestamp).format("DD. MMMM YYYY");
```

I have tried the following, but it does NOT work:

```
// Attempt #1:
var date = moment.lang('de').unix(valueTimestamp).format("DD. MMMM YYYY");
// Attempt #2:
var date = moment.local('de').unix(valueTimestamp).format("DD. MMMM YYYY");
```

How do I achieve that the month name will be German?

**EDIT**

I included the locales.js file and create a js fiddle which will demonstrate my problem:

https://jsfiddle.net/e3a7bgLu/

The console displays the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: moment.locale(...).unix is not a function
```

Comment: `moment.locale('de');` should work. Be sure to include the german locale file.

Comment: when I use lang('de') or local('de') my console says "moment.lang(...).unix is not a function"

Comment: @Pataar: I included this file here: https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/develop/src/locale/de.js  But my console says `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word` because of the line `export default ...`

Comment: try to use https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/develop/locale/de.js this file. The other one is for developing purposes.

Comment: @Pataar: i included the locales.js file, but still have the same error. I edited my post. Here comes a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e3a7bgLu/

Comment: @Max you have the wrong order : https://jsfiddle.net/e3a7bgLu/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the unix constructor AFTER you are defining a locale.. So you're defining a locale onto nothing.

You need to create the moment first before defining a locale.

So moment will be created from the `.unix()` method, and from this returned result, you can define a locale onto it.

```
moment.unix(1414543560).locale('de').format("DD. MMMM YYYY");
```

Should do the trick! :)

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e3a7bgLu/1/)

Answer (score 1):

I've updated the fiddle you posted.
Should work this way.
https://jsfiddle.net/e3a7bgLu/2/

So first call `moment.locale` and then call the `moment.unix` function.